# Bitbucket cannot execute git upload-pack

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to clone a repository, but I get an error message, stating the following whenever I try that:

```
Bitbucket cannot not execute "git upload-pack ...". The command is not supported as entered.

Ensure you are using a supported SCM, check the syntax and try again.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have read up a bit, and a lot of people link this to SSH authentication. However, I have my keys all set up and I'm being asked to authenticate for every try.

The keys were generated with ssh-keygen, and the passphrase I enter is correct.

I can't really figure out the problem. I tried cloning various repos, but I end up with this every time.

So far I tried to clone the repository with the git bash, as well as with the help of the TortoiseGit GUI.

It might be worth mentioning I am using an SSH path.

EDIT: I tried several other repositories now. I always end up with this error. I guess it must be something local or something about my keys.

Comment: I'm having the same problem since today. Which Git-Version are you using? I just updated my Git for Windows yesterday (currently using git version 2.14.0.windows.1). Could be related...

Comment: 2.14.0 as well. Fresh download.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/36028 Thanks for your hint. I guess we are not the only ones with this problem. I will downgrade and try it with 2.13. I didn't think this could be the cause.

Comment: I will switch to HTTPS instead of SSH for now, so I don't have to go back to 2.13. I also requested my company to open a ticket at Atlassian to get this fixed (I think there is no public bugtracker for Bamboo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a problem **introduced with Git for Windows 2.14.0**. There is an incompatibility on Bitbucket SSH with the `git upload-pack` command over SSH.

This explains also, why HTTPS is not affected.

In the following commit, `git_connect` was changed to use `git upload-pack` instead of `git-upload-pack` and Bitbucket is not happy with that (*The command is not supported as entered*).
https://github.com/git/git/commit/40023e58cda656326287d77358514acb262b7484

Also see the commit's message:

> **git_connect: prefer Git's builtins over dashed form**
>
> This helps with minimal installations such as MinGit that refuse to
>   waste .zip real estate by shipping identical copies of builtins (.zip
>   files do not support hard links).

GitLab was running into the same problem:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/36028

I could only verify this on Bitbucket v4.8.1, maybe this is fixed in a later version.

**Workaround:**

Roll back to Git 2.13.x or switch to HTTPS.

**Solution:**

The issue has been addressed in https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10013. The commit has been reverted in Git for Windows. The Version v2.14.0.windows.2 should fix the issue (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.14.0.windows.2).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to boksoop's comment, I tried to go back to Git 2.13.2.

It's working perfectly fine with that version. I would avoid upgrading to 2.14 for now as it seems.

Comment: as it could be found otherwise on the web - version 2.14.1 has a fix for it.